# How to calculate the total sum of a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8.1, addition

I am trying to calculate the total of a column in a list box. My code is below:

**Variables**

```
double VanTot = Menu.VanillaQ * 1.00;
        double LCTot = Menu.LCQ * 1.50;
        double ChocTot = Menu.ChocQ * 1.50;
```

**Listbox**

```
   if (Menu.VanillaQ > 0)
        {

            listBox2.Items.Add("£" + VanTot.ToString("N2")); 

        }

        if (Menu.LCQ > 0)
        {

            listBox2.Items.Add("£" + LCTot.ToString("N2"));

        }

        if (Menu.ChocQ > 0)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add("£" + ChocTot.ToString("N2"));
        }
```

How can I calculate the total by adding each 'Tot' and display it in this textbox:

```
   private void Totaltxt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Totaltxt_TextChanged method will get called when the corresponding textbox's text is changed in any way so I'm not sure how that applies to adding up the total. You could probably just insert the following line whenever you wanted the total to be calculated and displayed. I'm assuming "Totaltxt" is the name of your textbox.

`Totaltxt.Text = (VanTot + LCTot + ChocTot).ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the `Items` in the `ListBox` and `Sum` them, you could use `LINQ` `Sum` to help you. But you need some intermediate steps before you get there:

1. Cast your `ListBox.Items` from collection of `object` into `string`
2. Convert each element to number data type like, say, `decimal`
3. Sum the results

You could do this with `LINQ` one-liner like this:

```
decimal sum = listBox1.Items
               .Cast<string>() //read (1)
               .Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x)) //read (2)
               .Sum(); //read (3)
```